# Turning ethernet on/off

Tags: ethernet, pcap

I am porting a DOS application to linux and don't know a hell of a lot about linux. The application is a machine controller which uses ethernet as a high-speed serial port. Networking has nothing to do with it, the computer and machine just broadcast raw packets at each other over a crossover ethernet cable. No TCP or anything like it, they're both in promiscuous mode sending plain ethernet packets. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and I haven't found a way to enable the ethernet port without the damn thing trying to establish a network connection. Surely this must be doable- can anybody help me out? I'm thinking I can use pcap to send and receive the packets, but I'm stuck at the starting gate here.

Comment: Is there any reason why assigning a static IP from an rfc1918 range would interfere with your setup?

Comment: I don't see how it could hurt- would that prevent it from trying to connect to a network? I'll give it a try and find out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That worked! thank you very much.

Comment: Great, good to hear!

Comment: There are some other commands to do this [listed in this article](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu-enable-and-disable-the-network-interface/).